# After removing Docker container, why is it automatically re-created?

Tags: docker, containers, linux

I'm using ubuntu-16.04 desktop and installed `Docker-1.5-1` and `docker-engine-17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial`, in which I installed `openmedicus/phplist`. My aim is to remove the container, and the image as well.

The issue is that the container is removed successfully but after some time the container is automatically created with a different container ID.

I even tried to remove images also but faced the same issue.

Trying to remove images:

```
$ docker images | grep phplist
openmedicus/phplist             latest              24d3de5279cb        4 months ago        694MB

$ docker rmi openmedicus/phplist:latest --force
Untagged: openmedicus/phplist:latest
Untagged: penmedicus/phplist@sha256:6ac98b2f624eb8cd61b64c4b398650975a876224d5925175c58ff0c1b05a2593

$ docker images | grep phplist    ## Delete Sucessfully
```

Now trying to remove container :

```
$ docker ps
b02b641560e8        24d3de5279cb             "/bin/sh -c /usr/s..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                 
$ docker stop b02b641560e8
b02b641560e8

$ docker rm b02b641560e8 --force   # Remove Sucessfully
b02b641560e8
```

Again, the container is created automatically :

```
$ docker ps
2c78199dc40c        openmedicus/phplist      "/bin/sh -c /usr/s..."   29 seconds ago      Up 28 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                 phplist
```

How can I remove the Docker container and image permanently?

Comment: I highly doubt an `apt-get install docker-engine` would end up running any container, so there's probably something else you did and omitted in this question.

Comment: @Tensibai tried but not working

Comment: @nullpointer very strange behavior. Why isn't docker version 17 or so but 1.5?
docker --version

Comment: Tried what ? phplist is a mass mailing system, there's no chance it could get installed as a dependency. How did you install docker ?

Comment: @Tensibai tried reinstall docker and docker-engine then again tried to remove container but still same issue, install docker with 'apt-get`

Comment: Maybe just because phplist doesn't come with docker at all ? We can't guess what you have installed/selected ... search for what is launching docker commands to run a phplist instance, probably another daemon or a cronjob somewhere

Comment: @Tensibai see others container working fine means docker wokring fine. there is no cron for same, here I removed image as well as container of phplist then why created again even image removed ?

Comment: Just because there's something somewhere on your system doing a `docker run openmedicus/phplist`, check `/etc/systemd/system/docker-phplist.service` presence according to the docker-hub readme of the image you're listing: https://hub.docker.com/r/openmedicus/phplist/

Comment: @Tensibai it's bit simple issue, `docker-phplist.service` was re-created the container. Now issue resolved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

Something like watchtower maybe running and monitoring your host machine on which the containers are running. Watchtower can re-pull your images from a registry and re-launch a container for you. There are some tools similar to watchtower which do this.

Comment: This sounds plausible, I've had this before with an in-house daemon that pulled images and created containers.

Answer (score 0):

This can also com from swarm.
A look [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/why-the-containers-are-being-recreated-and-they-can-not-be-removed/55560) to find some more

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).